# Channel disconnected error message again and again - Flash builder 4

Tags: flash, channel, builder

I'm trying to use server capabilities Flash Builder 4. But using different ways (i use 5 or 6 tutorial) get one and the same error within a week - "Channel disconnected - Channel disconnected before an acknowledgment was received."
I looked up "gateway.php" and there was not even a closing tag ?>. Error repeated on a remote server (of course I changed all the settings to the mySQL database). Network monitor also gives error.
Show where I can find a solution, please? It may be to blame Zend? But how to update it?

Answer (score 1):

In your employeeService.php file - as shown below - set the port number to your MySQL port number. Default is 3306.

```
var $port = "3306";
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give an example of the error in [the tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/testdrive/articles/1_build_a_flex_app4.html)...

If you forget to edit searchBtn_clickHandler method, the Channel Disconnected error will occurs.

Wrong:

> getEmployeesResult.token =
>   employeeService.getEmployeesByName(searchTxt.text);

Correct:

> if(searchTxt.text!=""){
>   getEmployeesResult.token =
>   employeeService.getEmployeesByName(searchTxt.text);
>   } else{    getEmployeesResult.token =
>   employeeService.getEmployees(); }

Regards,